# Which Generic Finger Print Module will be best To incorporate in my ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax, fingerprint

We have an Asp.NET Web Application with web-forms  developed using VB.NET. We Need A finger print module which is generic and more preferably Ajax Based. 
Scenario is that we just want to click a `button` and go to finger print module which stores finger print information in our own database.
Should be a bit Customize-able, not the Finger Print Authentication and Verification module but the flow of the App.
Can any of you sujjest?

I left an Open Question so that i can get a generic solution use-able with all browsers. Chrome no more supports 3rd party  but certainly there must be Plugins to do this.

I came across the VeriFinger SDK here

[VeriFinger-SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/vf_sdk.html)

but it seems i need to write my own `plugin`  or `Appelet` to make their application workable with the webbroser, have any one used it with Web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think finger printer reader cannot direct communicate with web pages for this you should use some components that can communicate between device and web page.

http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2007/04/29/c-fingerprint-reader.aspx
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38881/Fingerprint-Reader-Integration-using-the-M2SYS-SDK